# Eclipse > Package Explorer - top 10 packages

Tags: eclipse

I've got a bunch of projects now that I've imported into Eclipse and they all show up in the Package Explorer of Eclipse.

So, I've got a list of around 30 packages (and growing!).

Can you only show the top 10 packages (but have the option of seeing previous packages if necessary - like Microsoft Word where you choose Open Recent and get a More option for previous files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "Recent packages" feature but you can configure package view by pressing the arrow in right upper corner and using `Filters...`. Then you can exclude "Closed" packages from being shown and close these you are not working with at the moment to get them hidden

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could either create multiple Working Sets and collapse all but the one you need right now. Or you could use multiple workspaces.

Either ways i dont think you can only show the most recent packages, but you can bring more organization in your package tree.

I would recommend Working Sets - personally i have quite a few of them and never had too much packages visible to cluster my screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact answer. But you can use Mylyn plugin for your need. When you click on the "Focus on Active task" button then you will see the accessed packages for that task.

More on Mylyn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150600/whats-the-best-way-to-start-using-mylyn). You can also use [Package Filter](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/10/29/improved-jdt-filtered-packageexplorer-for-eclipse-4-2-1/) plugin.